# how can i upload to Repo as part of a custom release build task

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I have built a Release pipeline custom task extension and this has been successful,  we are downloading a file from one location (Dev environment), then deploying it to the next (test environment)   I am wanting to have the build task capture the file and store it in the Repo as part of the task.

I've researched through all the Microsoft documentation, samples etc, but i am unable to find anything,  can anyone recommend some blogs/tutorials/examples that will allow me to do what i am after?

I also have a few other queries around custom build tasks and would love an end to end general tutorial,  i have found disparate information on the Microsoft Docs but piecing it all together is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i upload to Repo as part of a custom release build task

There is no such out of box method to upload file to Repo as part of a custom release build task. Because it is not recommended to use a script/build task to upload files directly to the repository without any checks.

If you are interested, you can try to use following method to do this:

Steps:

- Using task to download the file and you can copy them to your local repo directory. Then specify the Working Folder to the local repo directory in all Command Lines tasks.
- Run the build agent with an account that can push commits to TFS/Azure Devops.

Details steps:

1. Run `git add <filename>` command:

[image]

2. Run `git commit -m "Commit message"`.
3. Run `git push origin master`.

**Note:** Make sure you have install Git on your build agent machine.

Hope this helps.